# Determine gl_PointSize from distance of a GL_POINT to the camera

Tags: opengl, camera, vertex, glpointsize

I'm drawing GL_POINTS using 
`glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numberOfPoints)`
The size of each point is set in my vertex shader using `gl_PointSize`. I get the view matrix from `glm::lookAt(origin, eye, up)` The xyz position of a point is set using `gl_Position = view * proj * vec4(position, 1.0)` in the vertex shader. I'd like a point size to increase as its distance to the camera origin decreases, and the size to decrease as the distance from the camera origin increases. Just like normal perspective. How can I determine how large a point will be, from its distance to the camera?

Comment: That depends. How big do you *want* it to be? There's no right answer here; your question is not very specific.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a vertex shader I created recently to achieve this.

```
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 model, view, projection;
uniform float pointsize;
uniform vec3 cameraeye;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = pointsize - (distance(cameraeye, position.xyz) / pointsize);
}
```

- `pointsize` is the initial and max size of the point
- `cameraeye` is the `vec3` world position of the camera
- might be fine to remove the `model` matrix. I'm using a constant value of identity matrix in my implementation.

Comment: Good, but how to handle camera field of view
because if I changed the field of view the point size will still the same but other objects in the seen will change
thanks

Comment: @Abojemyeg good question. I think you can extract the near or far values from the `view` matrix and then add that to the pointsize equation.

Comment: could you please update the answer with the new equation because i don't even understand how near and far is related to field of view and even how field of view affect the object size on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Just set the point size to `ref / ptCoord.z`  with `ref` being the size of the point you want when it's at a distance of `1.0`.

Comment: Be advised that points have an implementation-defined maximum size.